# Does SQL Server support IS DISTINCT FROM clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

Does SQL Server support `IS DISTINCT FROM` statement which is SQL:1999 standard? E.g. the query

```
SELECT * FROM Bugs WHERE assigned_to IS NULL OR assigned_to <> 1;
```

can be rewritten using `IS DISTINCT FROM`

```
SELECT * FROM Bugs WHERE assigned_to IS DISTINCT FROM 1;
```

Comment: Yes, [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Looks like that feature isn't in a stable version of SQL Server yet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` is scheduled to be included in SQL Server 2022 (currently in public preview), see:

- [What's new in SQL Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#language)
- [IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

---

For earlier versions of SQL Server, the following SO question explains how to work around this issue with equivalent (but more verbose) SQL Server expressions:

- [How to rewrite IS DISTINCT FROM and IS NOT DISTINCT FROM in SQL Server 20008R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10416789/87698)