# How does if update() statement work in update trigger in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

update:
I `update` changed values in a column specifically in the other SQL script. So `IF UPDATE(column_name)` statement should work. For example, When I changed `LATTITUDE` AND `LONGITUDE` column in the same row, the `if update()` can capture the value changes while other `if update(column_name)` will return `false` as I did not `update` those unchanged values. But the problem is, I wish column `GROUP_ID` to be the same `SEQUENCE` value as those changes are in same row. The `SEQUENCE` value should only goes up when hitting next `row`. However, in my script, there is no way to store current `SEQUENCE` value in a variable.

[image]

---

I want to group those value changes in columns into SAME `SEQUENCE` value if in one row otherwise increasing `sequence` value.  However, `SEQUENCE` values always increases, is it because this `update trigger` fired more than once if multiple columns changed?

`@COUNT_update` is used to store current `sequence` value.
How do I fix it up then?
thanks

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AUDIT_SITE_UPDATE] ON [dbo].[SITE] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SITE_ID                [INT]
    DECLARE @SITE_DESCRIPTION       [varchar](1000) 
    DECLARE @SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER     [varchar](50) 
    DECLARE @LATTITUDE              [numeric](38, 10) 
    DECLARE @LONGITUDE              [numeric](38, 10) 
    DECLARE @INSERT_TIME            datetime2
    DECLARE @INSERT_USER            [varchar](256)
    DECLARE @seq_Next_Val INT=SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Audit_Seq, 
    -- UPDATE ROW

        if exists(select * from inserted) and exists(select * from deleted)
        BEGIN

        declare @COUNT_update int;
        set @COUNT_update =convert(int, (select current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'Audit_Seq')) ;

        if UPDATE(SITE_DESCRIPTION) 
            BEGIN   
                SELECT  @site_id=SITE_ID,
                        @SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER=SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,
                        @SITE_DESCRIPTION=SITE_DESCRIPTION,
                        @LATTITUDE=LATTITUDE,
                        @LONGITUDE=LONGITUDE,
                        @INSERT_TIME=INSERT_TIME,
                        @INSERT_USER=INSERT_USER 
                FROM deleted;
                        INSERT INTO  AUDIT_SITE(site_id,GROUP_ID,ACTIVITY,SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,INSERT_TIME,INSERT_USER) 
                    VALUES( @SITE_ID,@COUNT_update,'UPDATE',@SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,'SITE_DESCRIPTION',(SELECT SITE_DESCRIPTION FROM deleted)
                    ,(SELECT SITE_DESCRIPTION FROM inserted),@INSERT_TIME,@INSERT_USER)

            END

         if UPDATE(LATTITUDE)

            BEGIN   

                SELECT  @site_id=SITE_ID,
                        @SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER=SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,
                        @SITE_DESCRIPTION=SITE_DESCRIPTION,
                        @LATTITUDE=LATTITUDE,
                        @LONGITUDE=LONGITUDE,
                        @INSERT_TIME=INSERT_TIME,
                        @INSERT_USER=INSERT_USER 
                FROM deleted;
                        INSERT INTO  AUDIT_SITE(site_id,GROUP_ID,ACTIVITY,SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,INSERT_TIME,INSERT_USER) 
                    VALUES( @SITE_ID,@COUNT_update,'UPDATE',@SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,'LATTITUDE',(SELECT LATTITUDE FROM deleted)
                    ,(SELECT LATTITUDE FROM inserted),@INSERT_TIME,@INSERT_USER)

            END
        if UPDATE(LONGITUDE)
            BEGIN

                SELECT @site_id=SITE_ID,@SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER=SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,@SITE_DESCRIPTION=SITE_DESCRIPTION
            ,@LATTITUDE=LATTITUDE,@LONGITUDE=LONGITUDE,@INSERT_TIME=INSERT_TIME,@INSERT_USER=INSERT_USER FROM deleted;
                        INSERT INTO  AUDIT_SITE(site_id,GROUP_ID,ACTIVITY,SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,INSERT_TIME,INSERT_USER) 
                    VALUES( @SITE_ID,@COUNT_update,'UPDATE',@SOURCE_SITE_NUMBER,'LONGITUDE',(SELECT LONGITUDE FROM deleted)
                    ,(SELECT LONGITUDE FROM inserted),@INSERT_TIME,@INSERT_USER)            
            END

        END
END
```

Comment: This trigger is badly broken. Triggers don't fire once per column. They don't fire once per *row* either. They fire once per *statement*, which means `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows. They resemble tables. They should be used *as tables*. Not to obtain the values from arbitrary rows to set scalar variables.

Comment: Checking the number of rows in `inserted` and `deleted` is pointless as well. If a trigger on `UPDATE` fired, then both objects will contain at least 1 row (and the same number of rows).

Comment: You can't rely on `UPDATE(expressionHere)` to detect changes, it just indicate if the UPDATE updates a column, it can't detect if the column's value changes. Some ORMs even oversets all the columns even if a column's value didn't change at all, hence your `UPDATE(SITE_DESCRIPTION` will be always true. You need to use `inserted.column IS DISTINCT FROM deleted.column` instead of `UPDATE(expressionHere)`, or some emulation of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456737/does-sql-server-support-is-distinct-from-clause

Comment: The shortest, most readable way to check if a column was changed in an update trigger is this: `iif(inserted.Column = deleted.Column OR(inserted.Column is null and deleted.Column is null), 'equal', 'different')`

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I really wish Microsoft would hurry up and add `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` as defined by the SQL standard.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Don't hold your breath.... [last comment on this subject](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin) dates back to two years ago : "Don’t you love how useful M$ Connect is for raising issues? Almost 10 years go by after someone at Microsoft says this is a “Good Idea” and yet, no results …."