# Different conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

Is there a way to write this simplier?

```
WHERE
    (
        (@IdAgent IS NULL AND IdAgent IS NULL)
        OR
        (@IdAgent IS NOT NULL AND IdAgent = @IdAgent)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially remove one test, since `=` will never match a `NULL` and a non-`NULL` value:

```
WHERE
(@IdAgent IS NULL AND IdAgent IS NULL)
OR
  IdAgent = @IdAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075142/how-to-compare-values-which-may-both-be-null-is-t-sql/1075206#1075206), which, when applied to your situation, would look something like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT IdAgent
              INTERSECT
              SELECT @IdAgent)
```

You'll probably need to test it for performance in your particular environment to see if it doesn't run significantly slower than your present solution.