# How to call a user defined function with NULL values for one of its input parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My UDF's body has the following HAVING class.

```
HAVING   
         Company.Description            = @Company       AND
         SystemCustomerType.Description = @CustomerType
```

I tried to call this by this following syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM FunctionName('ABC_Company',NULL)
```

And also tried to set default value as `NULL` for `@CustomerType` parameter. And called the function by

```
SELECT * FROM FunctionName('ABC_Company',default)
```

Comment: As an aside, you might want to review your use of `HAVING`

Comment: Check for HAVING cluase... normally having clause used to filter on aggregation for filtering on column you might require to use WHERE itself

Comment: And your problem is? This should work fine on the syntax level, but as always, you can't compare `NULL` values using `=`; the function itself would have to accommodate for it using `IS NULL`, `ISNULL` or [some other technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075142/how-to-compare-values-which-may-both-be-null-is-t-sql).

Comment: It's missing a schema name so wont actually run.

Comment: @AlexK.: schema names are not required for table-valued functions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
where (Company.Description = @Company or @Company is null)
and (SystemCustomerType.Description = @CustomerType or @CustomerType is null)
```

Then use:

```
select * from FunctionName('ABC_Company',NULL)
```

Comment: **Thank you** JohnHC..  It is works fine... Cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

you can use NULL as parameter and then:

```
HAVING   
         Company.Description            = @Company       AND
         SystemCustomerType.Description = isnull(@CustomerType,'')
```

provided you don't need to differenciate between NULL and empty string

Comment: I think it is works, if we follow the logic NULLS are stored as an Empty string.

Answer (score 0):

'something' = NULL always returns false. To check if something is NULL use 'is'.

```
HAVING   
     Company.Description            = @Company       AND
     (SystemCustomerType.Description = @CustomerType 
     or (SystemCustomerType.Description is null and @CustomerType  is null))
```